# Pygame Fullscreen Button

Tags: python, pygame

A pygame tab has got 3 buttons: Close, minimize and fullscreen. You can check if the close button was pressed with this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                ...
```

But is there a way to check if the fullscreen button was pressed?

Comment: By looking at tab-completion I see `pygame.FULLSCREEN`. Does it do the job?

Comment: No, it doesn't for me.

Comment: So, what happens when you try `pygame.FULLSCREEN`? Does the program crash?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash, but it doesn't work too. It just always returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

When the screen size is changed, the `VIDEORESIZE` event is triggered. (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
        new_width, new_height = event.size
        # [...]
```